# Angular2, how to use ng.probe in the code to get a component instance

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I know we can use `ng.probe(element)` to get the debug element in console in dev mode.

And I know if you do a `query` in unit test, you can get a debug element which is exactly the same as `ng.probe`.

Is there any way to have this in the code ?

I know `ng.probe` is not available in `production mode` , but is there any way of getting a component instance of an element ?

Can we do :

```
    getComponentInstance(element){

       ng.probe(element) // pseudo code
   }
```

Basically, I want to look at some properties inside some components which I haven't created dynamically, so I don't have a reference to their instances, and I can't use `ViewChild` or similar simply because they're in my current component's view or content.

I know I can do this by creating some service and injecting it and stuff, but I don't have access to that component to inject a service to it.

If there isn't any ways, they how `ng.probe` is working and why didn't they provide this functionality ?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In e2e, we can query the DOM directly like below

```
async getDetails() {
        return await browser.executeScript('return ng.probe(document.querySelector("mat-table")).componentInstance._data');
    }
```

Whatever you do not the chrome console, we can get the data like above

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a parent components constructor you can inject:

[ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

```
constructor(private elm: ElementRef) { }
```

Then you should be able to query child components inner html to get the same access one can get from the unit testing `query()`.

For example I have a parent component that calls a internal library of components my company has created for us to use:

```
 <dt-panel class="panel-bottom">
    <dt-panel-header class="transaction-history-panel-header">
        <dt-panel-title><i class="zmdi zmdi-share"></i> Transaction History</dt-panel-title>
        <dt-panel-actions class="amount-due-summary">
            <span>Total Amount Due <span class="amount-due">{{calculateTotalAmountDueDisplayValue() | currency: 'USD':true}}</span></span>
            <em>(Days Past Due: {{account?.daysPastDue}})</em>
        </dt-panel-actions>
    </dt-panel-header>
    <dt-panel-content>
        <dt-tabs class="transaction-history">
            <dt-tab-content tabTitle="Receipts" class="recent-payments">
                <recent-payments *ngIf="!loading" [receipts]="receipts" ...></recent-payments>
                    <div class="loading" *ngIf="loading">
                        <dt-loader [selectedLoader]="'ball-pulse'" wild></dt-loader>
                    </div>
            </dt-tab-content>
            <dt-tab-content tabTitle="Amount Due">
                <amount-due *ngIf="!loading" [amountDues]="amountDues" [paymentPlan]="paymentPlan"></amount-due>
                <div class="loading" *ngIf="loading">
                    <dt-loader [selectedLoader]="'ball-pulse'" wild></dt-loader>
                </div>
            </dt-tab-content>
            <dt-tab-content *ngIf="showCashierTab()" tabTitle="Cashier" class="cashier">
                <add-payment-form [payment]="payment" ...
                    (submitPaymentEvent)="submitPayment()"></add-payment-form>
            </dt-tab-content>
        </dt-tabs>
    </dt-panel-content>
</dt-panel>
```

This 'parent' component uses child components prefixed with a 'dt-' brought in by an npm package. Also additional child components from the project are used.

Using this, I am able to get a reference to an element that is inside one of the child components in which I do not have direct access to:

```
this.elm.nativeElement.querySelector('dt-list-item').click();
```

Notice there are no 'dt-list-items' in the html in the parent view. However the 'dt-tabs' component does contain 'dt-list-items'. I needed to call a click method on the first one to get the tab group back to its initial state, this is how i did it.

Hope this helps you.